# How can I satisfy Audacity asking for libavformat.so.53, while Ubuntu 14.04 has libavformat.so.54?

Tags: 14.04, video, ffmpeg, audacity

I am using Audacity 2.0.5. I have been trying to edit video files. I know that Audacity is an audio DAW, but I recently learned that it was possible to import a file through ffmpeg and seperate the audio from the video. I followed the Audacity instructions about setting up Audacity so that it would do this. Then I found instructions on where to locate the libraries when this was done, but I got an error message.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. What I discovered is my computer has libavformat.so.54. Is there a way to change it to 53?

Comment: It is not available for > 14.04. It would not be a good idea, since other software might depend on it as well and might break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good chance, that `libavformat.so.54` contains all the symbol needed by Audacity. Tell Audacity to work with that. If necessary trick it, by creating a symlink somewhere, e. g.:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.54 ~/libavformat.so.53
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and two things happened. First the good news: the terminal did not report an error message. But second, I am getting the same message as before in Audacity.

Comment: Did you point Audacity to either `/usr/lib/$(uname -m)-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.54` or `~/libavformat.so.53`?

Comment: I might have it working now.

Answer (score -2):

You can remove the package. `wget` the correct deb package for your system from:

http://pkgs.org/

`sudo dpkg -i <package>`

Comment: Remove the package? it *is* the correct one for 14.04, other software might break. Moreover, it is not available in your link. Did you even check?

Comment: It is available. You can convert an rpm package to a deb package.

Comment: @nicox, I am trying to follow your instructions but am having some difficulty. I removed the package and put in the first link you told me about. I tried the second link but the system timed out and didn't like it. I typed sudo apt-get remove package followed by wget and the first link. Secondly, I do not know how to convert an rpm package to a deb package.

Comment: http://pkgs.org/altlinux-sisyphus/classic-i586/libavformat53-0.8.11-alt1.i586.rpm.html. Read through the Install Howto, before trying to convert.